# Error when transferring dataframe to excel in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, export-to-excel

when I want to save in **xls** format, the error is:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlwt'

when I want to save in **xlsx** format, the error is:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'

So how to install both of the module?

Comment: OK done by my self :D

just **pip install xlwt** or **conda install xlwt** if using conda environment

and so on openpyxl  **pip install openpyxl** or **conda install openpyxl**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your venv is activated and type `pip install xlwt openpyxl` and then this should work.

If it doesn't Excel can import CSVs, as created by data_frame.to_csv; so you can try that.

If neither works, put up a sample of your dataframe and leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install xlwt
pip install openpyxl
```

note: you can add data to xlsx file using openpyxl and append data to already existing xlsx file using openpyxl